# append is making all draggable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a test page with hardcoded draggable div's

```js
$('body').append('<div id="'+imagename+'" class="draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"><img src="uploads/pages/'+imagename+'"><div class="edit" style="display: none;"><a href="#" title="Click and Drag Widget" class="move">Drag</a><a href="#" title="Remove Widget" class="delete">Remove</a>        </div></div>').draggable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="draggable"><img src="uploads/pages/88bus-ben-kenyonLane.jpg"></div>
```

```
    $('body').append('<div id="'+imagename+'" class="draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"><img src="uploads/pages/'+imagename+'"><div class="edit" style="display: none;"><a href="#" title="Click and Drag Widget" class="move">Drag</a><a href="#" title="Remove Widget" class="delete">Remove</a>        </div></div>').draggable();
```

I have a script to append the body and insert a new draggable div.
When I try to drag the new div the existing div's move with it. but the hardcoded ones also move independently.

Comment: Show "hardcoded ones" if that is markup, that is unclear.  Does not the UI `.draggable` add `ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle` so you do not have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue IS that you made the body draggable but by breaking it down, removing the hidden style so I could see stuff it seems to work.
Note one change, having an image name with an extension seemed odd so I used a hard coded one since that was an unknown not posted in your question.

NOTE: you still need to make your first one draggable so we do that

```js
$(function() {
  var imagename = "freddyflintstone";
  var dlinks = '<div class="edit" ><a href="#" title="Click and Drag Widget" class="move">Drag</a><a href="#" title="Remove Widget" class="delete">Remove</a>dlinks</div>';
  var dnew = $('<div id="' + imagename + '" class="draggable"><img src="uploads/pages/' + imagename + '.jpg"/>dnew</div>').append(dlinks);
  dnew.draggable();
  $('#draggable').draggable();//added this
  dnew.appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="draggable">hi<img src="uploads/pages/88bus-ben-kenyonLane.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly Mark thanks for the example and explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct because you apply `draggable` method on `body` and when you drag a div, in fact whole of body dragged not this div.

Please see [**incorrect way (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/f7zvbyaL/8/) that I created from your code and inspect on body. You can see `draggable` apply on `body`.

If you do it like below, you see it works properly.

[**Correct way (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/pwsec14b/1/)